# Yii2-Bootstrap: Object of class yii\bootstrap\NavBar could not be converted to string Error

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am about to integrate twitter bootstrap theme in yii2. I have added css & js files in the bootstrapThemeAsset & bootstrapPluginAsset. Tried converting nav bar into bootstrap nav bar as follows.

```
    <?= NavBar::begin(['class' => 'navbar-default navbar-static-side'])?>
    <!--<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">-->
```

th throws me the exception

```
PHP Recoverable Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Object of class yii\bootstrap\NavBar could not be converted to string
```

couldn't get this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NavBar::begin start widget, not return string

use

```
 <?php NavBar::begin(['class' => 'navbar-default navbar-static-side'])?>
```

P.S>

```
 <?= NavBar::begin(['class' => 'navbar-default navbar-static-side'])?>
```

is the same as

```
 <?php echo NavBar::begin(['class' => 'navbar-default navbar-static-side'])?>
```

Comment: hey i need to know do i have to convert the HTML content between begin() & end() into yii2 specific code (as that of i converted:see commented part in question) for bootstrap???